# Are TOAST rows written for UPDATEs not changing the TOASTable column?

Tags: postgresql, update, storage

Imagine I have a table in Postgres 13 like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.people (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    full_name character varying(255),
    bio text
);
```

I then insert a row with enough characters for the bio to be written to a TOAST table:

```sql
# insert into people values (1, 'joe user', (SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT chr((65 + round(random() * 25)) :: integer) FROM generate_series(1,4000)), '')));
INSERT 0 1
```

Finally, I update the row without changing the TOAST column:

```sql
# update people set full_name='jane user' where id=1;
UPDATE 1
```

Does the `UPDATE` change any rows (or require any writes at all) in the associated TOAST table?

Context: I'm working with some database tables that have thousands of transactions per second, and the observed write load on the server is quite high. I'm wondering if `UPDATE`s to tuples with large values in TOAST but the TOAST value itself mostly not changing is contributing to the write load and is worth optimising.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a clear answer in [the manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html#STORAGE-TOAST-ONDISK)

> During an `UPDATE` operation, values of unchanged fields are normally
> preserved as-is; so an `UPDATE` of a row with out-of-line values
> incurs no TOAST costs if none of the out-of-line values change.

That's one of the main benefits of an `UPDATE` over `DELETE` + `INSERT` (while either writes a new row version).

But there is some fine print to "unchanged". See:

- [Does UPDATE write a new row version for unchanged, TOASTed values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308776/does-update-write-a-new-row-version-for-unchanged-toasted-values/308779#308779)