# Separate small column updated a lot from large jsonb columns to optimize performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-performance, mvcc

A table has the following structure:

- a: id
- b: large jsonb
- c: large jsonb
- d: timestamp

Looking at stats in 2 weeks, see many updates:

- 90k requests updates the `d` field alone (total time: 25min measured from app)
- 90k requests updates the "large jsonb" fields (total time: 6h30 measured from app)

Since Postgres follows MVCC pattern which rewrites rows on update, is it interesting to change the table structure to have `d` in a separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not necessary. The large JSON values seem to be stored out of line in a TOAST table. Then the update of `d` only has to write a new row to the main table, but the TOAST values stay the same.

If the JSON values were small enough to be stored in the main table, modifying `d` would be much more expensive, because it had to write the whole row with the JSONs in it again. Then it might make sense to consider such a separation.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Laurenz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/176905/laurenz-albe) advised, column values that are stored out of line in a [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/storage-toast.html) table and are not touched in the `UPDATE` can stay as they are, saving work and storage. (Old and new row version of the main relation point to the same TOAST entry.)

**But** there is fine print to this.

#### Are you toasting, yet?

The row size has to exceed [`TOAST_TUPLE_THRESHOLD`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/27b77ecf9f4d5be211900eda54d8155ada50d696/src/include/access/heaptoast.h#L50) (typically 2 kb) to be considered. Some columns may already be compressed. The TOAST mechanism will then try to compress more columns until the size falls below [`TOAST_TUPLE_TARGET`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/27b77ecf9f4d5be211900eda54d8155ada50d696/src/include/access/heaptoast.h#L50) (typically the same 2 kb). Only if it fails to achieve that, it will start moving data to the TOAST table, one column at a time.

The default compression algorithm `pglz` compresses `jsonb` data around factor 3 to 4 in my quick test. (Varies depending on content.) So the raw size of your row has to exceed around 7 kb, before anything is TOASTed. And then possibly only one of your two "large" columns. That may leave you with medium size tuples in the main relation of up to 2 kb, which brings us back to your initial considerations.

Have a closer look at the compressed(!) size of your `jsonb` values, and the actual tuple size in the main relation (min, max, avg, mean) to arrive at an educated decision.

Here is a blog post with useful queries:

- https://jongsma.wordpress.com/2022/06/17/postgresql-toast-tables-and-referencing-rows/

#### "Unchanged"

About:

> 90k requests updates the "large jsonb" fields ...

Commonly, an update only actually change one or the other column, or updates one or the other without actual changes. TOASTed column values stay the same if the column is "unchanged". To be precise: if the column is not targeted in the `UPDATE`. If you overwrite a column with an unchanged value, that counts as "changed". Postgres won't verify that the value actually changed and write a new row version, including TOAST. Avoid such "empty" updates with smart query design. See:

- [Does UPDATE write a new row version for unchanged, TOASTed values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308776/does-update-write-a-new-row-version-for-unchanged-toasted-values/308779#308779)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860)

#### Compression algorithm `lz4`

If what you disclosed is all that happens in your table, consider the non-default LZ4 compression algorithm. (Available since **Postgres 14**.) It's **much** faster, while compressing a little less. (Resulting size was ~ 15 % bigger in my quick test for `jsonb` data.) Here is blog post with an exhaustive comparison from when it was first released:

- https://www.postgresql.fastware.com/blog/what-is-the-new-lz4-toast-compression-in-postgresql-14

See:

- [Does UPDATE write a new row version for unchanged, TOASTed values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/308776/does-update-write-a-new-row-version-for-unchanged-toasted-values/308779#308779)
- [Disable TOAST compression for all columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/315063/disable-toast-compression-for-all-columns/315067#315067)

**In summary**, use the appropriate compression algorithm, then use smart queries, then gather valid statistics on your data, and **then** decide whether breaking out one or the other column can make sense. There has to be a clear benefit to justify the overhead.

Comment: Thank Erwin for this precious information.