# DELETE plus INSERT, or UPSERT row?

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I'm trying to figure out the fastest way to:

- INSERT a row if it doesn't exist
- REPLACE (all columns at once) the row if it exists

I thought about `DELETE` + `INSERT`, but that looks like 2 scans
and if I do an `INSERT` + `ON CONFLICT`, I get a huge query where everything has to be duplicated.

Is there a generally acknowledged method to do this?

Comment: "*that looks like 2 scans*" - If your table is indexed, it ideally would be 2 seeks which is rather fast. I wouldn't go about complicating it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a *generally acknowledged* case for [**UPSERT**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) (`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT .. DO UPDATE ...`).

And the simple case only involves a **single index scan**. (Aside from possible locking and writing and index updates.)

For one, race conditions under concurrent write load are typically handled smarter. See:

- [How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217872/939860)

And it's also typically cheaper. *"REPLACE (all columns at once) the row if it exists"* sounds mildly suspicious. If "the row exists", at least one or more columns must be identical. On the other hand, `UPDATE` writes a new row version in any case (if it writes at all). That's still cheaper than `DELETE` + `INSERT` if toasted fields can be carried over, or index entries with a H.O.T. `UPDATE`. See:

- [Are TOAST rows written for UPDATEs not changing the TOASTable column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/301662/are-toast-rows-written-for-updates-not-changing-the-toastable-column/301663#301663)
- [Update all columns from another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63871/update-all-columns-from-another-table/63886#63886)

Your *"huge query where everything has to be duplicated"* indicates potential for optimization or possible misunderstandings. If that might be the case, show the query you have, together with your version of Postgres, a reproducible setup, and the desired result (in a new question!).

That said, if you don't have toasted columns, and no heavy concurrent write load, and few indexes (or just one), then `DELETE` + `INSERT` is only moderately more expensive.

When replacing large parts of a table without concurrent write load, it may even be cheaper. You might `VACUUM` the table between `DELETE` and `INSERT` ... But that's digressing from the use case in the question.

Comment: In my specific case, the table is used to store the results of some simulations. Besides the few columns that identify the process, every other column has new numbers at each iteration, which means that ON conflict causes me to duplicate the 31 other columns in the query. There is nothing bad with it, but that makes quite a large query as everything has to be there twice.

Comment: @Thomas: `UPDATE` requires you to spell out target columns. But shorter syntax may be available. You might post another question with the necessary details if that's relevant.

Comment: I've posted another question to see if the syntax could be simplified.